# Error with ExpressJS when serving static files - The Resource was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch

Tags: express, http-status-code-404, mime-types, phaser-framework

I am trying to develop a multiplayer HTML 5 game with Phaser3, ExpressJS (& SocketIO in the future).

this is my
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrssA.png)

I want to serve my phaser game via the index.html to the client , but whenever I try to load the scripts I get MIME Errors on Firefox and 404 not found on Chromium.

These are the [Firefox errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii5I1.png) and these are the [Chromium errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgCDa.png).

**server.ts**

```
// @ts-ignore
import { Socket } from "socket.io";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import * as path from "path";


const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
// @ts-ignore
const uuid = require("uuid");

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req: Request, res: Response) {
res.sendFile(path.resolve('./index.html'));
});

class GameServer {


constructor() {
    this.socketEvents();
}

public connect(port: number): void {
    http.listen(port, () => {
        console.info(`Listening on port ${port}`);
    });
}

private socketEvents(): void {
    io.on('connected', () => {
        console.log("user connected");
    });
}

}

const gameSession = new GameServer();

gameSession.connect(3000);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="public/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="public/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/dist/bundle.js" async></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9000/livereload.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "lasttryphaser",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "npm run lint",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p .",
    "prestart:dev": "npm run prestart",
    "start:dev": "webpack -w & tsc -w --noEmit src/server/server & nodemon src/server/server.js",
    "build:release": "webpack --env=dev --optimize-minimize",
    "prestart": "npm i && tsc -p ./",
    "start": "webpack && node ./src/server/server.js",
    "webpack": "webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "phaser": "^3.20.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/pixi.js": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.4",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.6",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.13.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "resolve": "^1.12.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

**webconfig.dev.js**

```
    const path = require("path");
const tsconfig = require("./tsconfig.json");
const { TsConfigPathsPlugin } = require("awesome-typescript-loader");
const LiveReloadPlugin = require("webpack-livereload-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./main",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    mode: "development",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
        plugins: [new TsConfigPathsPlugin()],
    },
    plugins: [
        new LiveReloadPlugin({
            port: 9000,
            hostname: "localhost",
            protocol: "http",
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "typings"),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                ],
                options: tsconfig,
            },
            {
                test: /\.spec.ts$/,
                use: "ignore-loader",
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
  {
"compilerOptions": {
  "allowJs": true,
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
  "module": "commonjs",
  "noEmitOnError": false,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "alwaysStrict": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "sourceMap": true
},
"paths": {
  "client/*": ["src/client/*"],
  "server/*": ["src/server/*"],
  "shared/*": ["src/shared/*"]
},
"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./node_modules/phaser/types"
],
"files": [
  "src/server/server.ts",
  "main.ts",
  "./node_modules/phaser/types/phaser.d.ts"
],
"exclude": ["node_modules", "*.spec.ts"],
"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
  "transpileOnly": true
}
```

}

I looked up everything I could possibly find on the Internet, and read a book about building multiplayer games with phaser. I tried rebuilding that application from the book (which executes fine on all browsers) and I still get those errors.

Thanks for any help